# How to change Picker font colour and size in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

I'm new to Xamarin and I'm currently doing a project in Xamarin Forms PCL.

Is there a way to change the font colour and size of Picker?

```
  <Picker x:Name="pkr_color" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    BackgroundColor="#ededed" Title="Select Color">
      <Picker.Items>
        <x:String>Red</x:String>
        <x:String>Blue</x:String>
        <x:String>Green</x:String>
      </Picker.Items>
    </Picker>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use custom render and implement in all platforms.

Comment: You can use ```TextColor``` and ```TitleColor``` to change the font color and ```HeightRequest``` to change the size.

Answer (score 5):

Font size of a picker can be changed with PCL code.

Create MainPage.xaml file

```
<Picker x:Name="PickerList" Title="Select Any One" IsVisible="False" SelectedIndexChanged="PickerList_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Picker.Items>
            <x:String>Option 1</x:String>
            <x:String>Option 2</x:String>
            <x:String>Option 3</x:String>
        </Picker.Items>
    </Picker>
    <Label x:Name="PickerLabel" Text="Tap to Select Picker" FontSize="14" HorizontalOptions="Start">
        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
    </Label>
```

Create MainPage.xaml.cs file

```
private void PickerList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PickerLabel.Text = PickerList.Items[PickerList.SelectedIndex];
        // PickerLabel.Text = PickerList.SelectedItem.ToString() ;
    }

    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PickerList.Focus();
    }
```

this solves the problem for Android and IOS.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to write a custom renderer for each platform.

```
using System;
using Project.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Picker), typeof (CustomPickerRenderer))]
namespace Project.iOS
{
    public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);
            if (Control != null) {
                Control.TextColor = UIKit.UIColor.White;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example for iOS. This would change the color of the text, you will need to do something similar for Android, and just add your font sizing change as well.

Comment: Hello, I am using timepicker and customize minutes interval as 30 minutes. Now I want to display only 0 and 30 two value just like AM PM. I mean without repeating same value. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I Hope Below Code Helpful to Get Your TextColor

```
**In Xaml**

 <Picker SelectedIndexChanged="OnColorPickerSelected" TextColor="{Binding TextColor}"/>


**In Code Behind**

 private void OnColorPickerSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   ((ViewModel)BindingContext).Color= pkr_color.Items[pkr_color.SelectedIndex];

   ChooseColorPickerTextColor(((ViewModel)BindingContext).Color, pkr_color);
 }

**Implement ChooseColorPickerTextColor Method Here**

  private void ChooseColorPickerTextColor(string selectedColor, Picker pickerName)
    {
        Picker colorPickerTextColor = pickerName;

        if (selectedColor == "Red")
        {
            colorPickerTextColor.TextColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else if (selectedColor == "Yellow")
        {
            colorPickerTextColor.TextColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        else if (selectedColor == "Green")
        {
            colorPickerTextColor.TextColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else if (selectedColor == "Blue")
        {
            colorPickerTextColor.TextColor = Color.Blue;
        }
        else if (selectedColor == "Maroon")
        {
            colorPickerTextColor.TextColor = Color.Maroon;
        }
        else if (selectedColor == "Pink")
        {
            colorPickerTextColor.TextColor = Color.Pink;
        }
        else
        {
            colorPickerTextColor.TextColor = Color.Aqua;
        }
    }
```

By using "WidthRequest" We can Increase size of the picker

Answer (score 1):

For changing typeface, size, underline, text, textcolor, alert dialog button position, button text in Android native numberpicker (xamarin form picker), you can handle it with a custom render like this:

```java
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Graphics;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker), typeof(MyPickerRenderer))]
namespace Daddy.Droid
{
    public class MyPickerRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PickerRenderer
    {
        Typeface fontFace = null;
        private IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;
        private AlertDialog _dialog;
        public MyPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            AutoPackage = false;
        }
        [Obsolete("This constructor is obsolete as of version 2.5. Please use PickerRenderer(Context) instead.")]
        public MyPickerRenderer()
        {
            AutoPackage = false;
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null || e.OldElement != null || Control == null)
                return;

            fontFace = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(this.Context.Assets, "somefont.ttf");

            GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
            gd.SetStroke(0, Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            Control.SetBackground(gd);

            Control.TextSize = 14f;
            Control.SetTypeface(fontFace, TypefaceStyle.Normal);

            Control.Click += Control_Click;
        }
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            Control.Click -= Control_Click;
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Picker model = Element;
            NumberPicker picker = new NumberPicker(Context);

            int count = picker.ChildCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                Android.Views.View v = picker.GetChildAt(i);
                if(v.GetType() == typeof(EditText))
                {
                    Java.Lang.Reflect.Field  field = picker.Class.GetDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
                    field.Accessible = true;
                    ((Paint)field.Get(picker)).SetTypeface(fontFace);
                    ((EditText)v).SetTypeface(fontFace, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                    picker.Invalidate();   
                }
            }

            if (model.Items != null && model.Items.Any())
            {
                picker.MaxValue = model.Items.Count - 1;
                picker.MinValue = 0;
                picker.SetDisplayedValues(model.Items.ToArray());
                picker.WrapSelectorWheel = false;
                picker.DescendantFocusability = DescendantFocusability.BlockDescendants;
                picker.Value = model.SelectedIndex;
                picker.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

            }


            var layout = new LinearLayout(Context) { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
            layout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            layout.AddView(picker);


            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, true);

            var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context); 
            builder.SetView(layout);

            builder.SetTitle(model.Title ?? "");

            builder.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (s, a) =>
            {
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
                Control?.ClearFocus();
                _dialog = null;
            });

            builder.SetPositiveButton("This One", (s, a) =>
            {
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Picker.SelectedIndexProperty, picker.Value);
                if (Element != null)
                {
                    if (model.Items.Count > 0 && Element.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                        Control.Text = model.Items[Element.SelectedIndex];
                    ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
                    Control?.ClearFocus();
                }
                _dialog = null;
            });

            _dialog = builder.Create();

            _dialog.DismissEvent += (ssender, args) =>
            {
                ElementController?.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
            };
            _dialog.Show();


            Android.Widget.Button nbutton = _dialog.GetButton((int)Android.Content.DialogButtonType.Positive);
            nbutton.SetTypeface(fontFace, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            nbutton.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#33b5e5"));
            nbutton.TextSize = 16f;
            LinearLayout layOut = (LinearLayout)nbutton.Parent;
            layOut.SetGravity(GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal);
            Android.Views.View v1 = layOut.GetChildAt(1);
            v1.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;


            int res = Resources.GetIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
            TextView textView = (TextView)_dialog.FindViewById(res);
            textView.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Gray);
            textView.SetTypeface(fontFace, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            textView.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question only asked about the font color and size of the picker, not about the other stuff. Also, [you may want to read up on this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - code-only answers are usually not the most optimal way to answer questions here. (If you referenced individual properties or methods, or gave an individual method as an example, that'd be okay.)

Answer (score -2):

Put the `Label` and `Picker` in the same `Grid cell`.Don't set `Title` of the `picker` instead the `Text` of the `Label` will work as `Title`.

```
<Label x:Name="PickerLabel" Text="Picker Title" TextColor="Any Color"></Label>
         <Picker x:Name="Picker" SelectedIndexChanged="Picker_SelectedIndexChanged" TextColor="Any Color" />
```

Now make the `Text` of Label `Invisible` when an `Item` is `selected` from `Picker`.

```
void Picker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            PickerLabel.IsVisible = false;
        }
```