# Is there any way to change the Picker Title FontSize and FontFamily in PCL project

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

this is my picker

```
<Picker  Grid.Row="1"  
         Grid.Column="3" 
         Title="Select LeaveType" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding LeaveTypeCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"
         ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLeaveType}" 
         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

I want to add  title Fontsize and  FontFamily to the 
 picker can someone help me in this issue ,thank you.

Comment: this is the picker I wanted to change  <Picker  Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="3" Title="Select LeaveType " ItemsSource="{Binding LeaveTypeCollection, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLeaveType}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately these properties are not exposed by the Xamarin Picker control and you will need to implement some sort of workaround.

There is some chat about this on the Xamarin forum, with [a workaround detailed here that uses a label with a hidden picker](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/26724/font-size-and-styles-with-picker?), where the picker is revealed when the label is clicked. This allows the label to be customised with your font size and font family, to give the appearance of a styled picker.

There are also some answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900804/how-to-change-picker-font-colour-and-size-in-xamarin-forms) that details how to use a custom renderer to solve your problem.