# How to change the change cancel and ok buttons' color in the picker?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, colors, picker

I'm using a custompicker in my app and I need to change the cancel and ok buttons' color. I recently changed the whole theme of timepicker and datepicker for android by adding this code to the style file:

```
 <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/TimePickerTheme</item>

item name="colorAccent">#039BE5</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  </style>
  <style name="TimePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#039BE5</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  </style>
```

Is that a similar code that I can add for the picker?

Comment: Clarification: This question and the accepted answer are specific to (Xamarin) Android; it isn't a *cross-platform* solution for setting picker buttons color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you change the theme   `<item name="colorAccent">#039BE5</item>` may affect the theme of other controls,you could only change the color in your CustomRenderer like this:

```
public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
{
    private Context context;
    private IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;
    private AlertDialog _dialog;

    public CustomPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null) return;
        Control.Click += Control_Click1;
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Control.Click -= Control_Click1;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void Control_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Picker model = Element;

        var picker = new NumberPicker(Context);
        if (model.Items != null && model.Items.Any())
        {
            picker.MaxValue = model.Items.Count - 1;
            picker.MinValue = 0;
            picker.SetDisplayedValues(model.Items.ToArray());
            picker.WrapSelectorWheel = false;
            picker.DescendantFocusability = DescendantFocusability.BlockDescendants;
            picker.Value = model.SelectedIndex;
        }

        var layout = new LinearLayout(Context) { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
        layout.AddView(picker);

        ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, true);

        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
        builder.SetView(layout);
        builder.SetTitle(model.Title ?? "");

        //change the text or color here
        builder.SetNegativeButton(Html.FromHtml("<font color='#039BE5'>Cancel</font>"), (s, a) =>
        {
            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
            // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
            // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
            Control?.ClearFocus();
            _dialog = null;
        });

         //change the text or color here
        builder.SetPositiveButton(Html.FromHtml("<font color='#039BE5'>OK</font>"), (s, a) =>
        {
            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Picker.SelectedIndexProperty, picker.Value);
            // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed on SelectedIndexChanged.
            // In this case, the Element & Control will no longer exist.
            if (Element != null)
            {
                if (model.Items.Count > 0 && Element.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                    Control.Text = model.Items[Element.SelectedIndex];
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
                // It is also possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
                // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
                Control?.ClearFocus();
            }
            _dialog = null;
        });

        _dialog = builder.Create();
        _dialog.DismissEvent += (ssender, args) =>
        {
            ElementController?.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
        };
        _dialog.Show();
    }
}
```

**update**
i test it on Tablet emulator,it works well

[image]

Comment: This way is working fine on android v9.0 but I tried it on my 2 tablets it didn't change :(

Comment: i will test it later and tell you

Comment: @mohammadanouti i test it ,and it works,you could see the gif above.what's your tablet ?

Comment: It gives me this error when adding the code on new project: Member 'DescendantFocusability.BlockDescendants' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.                                                         
on this line:  picker.DescendantFocusability = DescendantFocusability.BlockDescendants;

Comment: I tried it on Huawei PLE-701L and SAMSUNG SM-T365 both are "Android 5.1" and nothing is changing

Comment: I replaced this: picker.DescendantFocusability = DescendantFocusability.BlockDescendants;
by this:  picker.DescendantFocusability = DescendantFocusability;
and it worked partially on my  Xiaomi POCOPHONE F1 "Android 9", I tap once and the color stay the same then unfocus and tap again and the color change, strange behavior.

Comment: I will try to find the appropriate equipment to test, maybe in a few days

Comment: How do the same for iOS?

Comment: [Beginning of an iOS renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39905053/199364). I don't think that example changes the button color, but it shouldn't be hard to add.